# Error While Connecting mysql.connector with python in Linux

Tags: python, mysql

I've installed the mysql.connector extension in my Linux OS. However, I'm still getting the error,
[image]"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql.connector'; 'mysql' is not a package"

Comment: Post your code and error as text in the question itself. Images can't be copied, googled or executed.

Comment: It's not installing in the system directory. Have you confirmed that your local directory is in `sys.path`?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I simply entered: import mysql.connector

Comment: ImportError: bad magic number in 'mysql': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'